# Android studio: how to use a database that is not your own

Tags: database, database-connection

My problem is how to use a database that is not your own to allow registration or login to the users of my application. For example i know how to do that using Facebook or Google (there are a lot of guides explaining that), but what if, for example, i wanted to use the database of any other site? My problem is to allow access of my app only to a users that are just members of a particular website. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use other websites **database** for authentication and registration if they have allowed you to do that or if they have **APIs** or **SDKs** to do that . Those amazing features offered by *Google* and *facebook* is possible because they have very rich **APIs** and **SDKs** for developers.

Comment: Thanks. But i read that is possible to authenticate with Oauth2 services. But i don't know exactly what is